# OnActivityResult doesn't update ImageView using Picasso

Tags: android, imageview, picasso, onactivityresult

Using following code to view captured image in an `ImageView`

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(this.requestCode == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
            File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/img.jpeg");             
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(imageFile).into(imageView);
        }
    }
```

**Problem:**
How Can I refresh `ImageView` in `onActivityResult(...)` as you can see I am using above code but always getting preview of old image, whereas i am getting new image inside storage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the code these lines of code for it:-

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(this.requestCode == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        File imageFile = new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/img.jpeg");             
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
        .load(imageFile)
        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
        .error(R.drawable.ic_lanucher)
        .noFade()
        .into(imageView)

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks +100... tapped as useful and will accept in five minutes.. this worked .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE )
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the captured image, you need to get bitmap from data i.e. your Intent object.

```html
if (responseCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
   Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
   if (bitmap != null) {
    
   // Here you will get bitmap , set bitmap in imageview
   }
  }
```